# Windows Phone 8.1 MVVM Setting ViewModel of View

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1

**MainPage.XAML**

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="MyApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait"  Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewModels:MainViewModel}">

    <!--FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"-->

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">



        <!--Pivot Control-->
        <phone:Pivot Title="MyApp">
            <!--Pivot item one-->
            <phone:PivotItem Header="Main">
                <Grid>

                </Grid>
            </phone:PivotItem>

            <!--Pivot item two-->
            <phone:PivotItem Header="Counter">
               <views:CounterView />
            </phone:PivotItem>
        </phone:Pivot>
    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

**CounterView.XAML**

```
 <UserControl x:Class="MyApp.Views.CounterView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
        FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
        Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DesignHeight="480" d:DesignWidth="480"          
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewModels:CounterViewModel}">


        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Blue" >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LightSensorInfo}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="75,137,0,316"/>
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

**Error:**

```
System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'LightSensorInfo' property not found on 'MyApp.ViewModels.MainViewModel' 'MyApp.ViewModels.MainViewModel' (HashCode=62333418). BindingExpression: Path='LightSensorInfo' DataItem='MyApp.ViewModels.MainViewModel' (HashCode=62333418); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'System.String')..
```

Why the hell Application tries to look into **MainViewModel** instead of **CounterViewModel** which I had set within a CounterView, DataContext?

In WPF, ResourceDictionary I used to set this too:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="viewModels:CounterViewModel">
    <views:CounterView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

But seems like WindowsPhone can't find DataType property so I commented out this part.

What I'm missing? Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to make own viewmodel to an usercontrol?

Comment: Perhaps because it that's the design time data context not the actual data context?

Comment: In my WP 8.1 app styles without `x:Key` are ignored if they are placed in external resource dictionary file. Try to move DataTemplate direct into `<App.Resources></App.Resources>`

Comment: Is it compilation or runtime error?

Comment: It's runtime error. Actually, it's not an Error it's just a message within an Output. I'm trying to have separate ViewModel for UserControl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoooah! Solution found!

**CounterView.XAML**

Wrong:

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewModels:CounterViewModel}"
```

Correct:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewModels:CounterViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Final:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.Views.CounterView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="480" d:DesignWidth="480">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <viewModels:CounterViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>


    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Blue" >
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LightSensorInfo}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="75,137,0,316"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Works like a charm! This is the only change I made - didn't have to do anything else.

Comment: Your answer is indeed correct, but, your "wrong" XAML is appropriate for designing your UserControl, so that Intellisense can find your ViewModel's properties. You can include both in your XAML.

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/07/solved-two-way-binding-inside-user.html

Looks like the answer is within that blog. Not tested yet, but it sounds logical:

> Please note: the data context property of the user control inherits
>   from the parent. A DataTemplate might like this. But user controls
>   don’t anticipate a data context type. Instead, they want properties
>   explicitly set. And we want to bind those properties.

Feel free to update me. :)